Ajv Schema validator fails to show source of compile error/warning
I have a composite json schema and I am switching over to using Ajv and have been slogging through cleaning up strict warnings. I am down to my last few but I cannot figure out the source of the warnings.  The console output from the compile function is
strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "properties" at "metadata.json#" (strictTypes)
util.js:175
strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "required" at "metadata.json#" (strictTypes)
util.js:175
2
strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "properties" at "metadata.json#" (strictTypes)
util.js:175
strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "required" at "metadata.json#" (strictTypes)
util.js:175
strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "properties" at "metadata.json#" (strictTypes)

I have tried both enabling the verbose option as well as adding my own logger, however, I am at a loss when trying to figure out where in the schema the compiler is when it hits this error.
Is there some way to view the source of the issue?

ajv strict does not follow the JSON Schema specification when set to true. Most of the strict settings are opinionated enforcement, some could be considered helpful though.   If you can show your schema, someone can help you finding where it's missing.  Seems like your metadata.json schema is missing properties from one or more schema definitions.

Thanks, it is a lengthy chunk of schema and probably considered proprietary. I have gone through it looking at every item and see no properties item missing a type. The question is more about a way to get Ajv to show you where it's at when it hits an "error".

You might try allErrors:true in the options object for the Ajv instance
